# Lucene QueryParser vs. TermQuery

Tags: java, search, lucene

I'm currently unsure about the behavior of the QueryParser vs. TermQuery in Lucene; I'm using Lucene 3.6.

In my example I'm try the following examples over the same index, where the field in question is set at `Field.Store.NO` and `Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS`.

```
Query q1 = new TermQuery(new Term("names", "test three"));

QueryParser q2p = new QueryParser(GenericIndexer.LUCENE_VERSION, "names", someAnalyzer);
Query q2 = q2p.parse("names:test three");
Query q3 = q2p.parse("names:\"test three\"");
```

In both cases `q2` and `q3` I'm unable to reproduce the same syntax as `q1`; by printing out the queries, I can see that:

- q1 = `names:test three`
- q2 = `names:test names:three`
- q3 = `names:"test three"`

Due to this difference queries `q2` and `q3` return no results, while query `q1` return the expected result.

**Question**: Is there a way to have the query parser to reproduce the same query as the TermQuery or am I missing some fundamental Lucene's notion here?

Note: for the QueryParser, the analyzer is the same one used during indexing, although I'm not sure how relevant this information is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your `TermQuery`, you are producing a single term `test three`.  Since this field is not analyzed, producing a single term is correct.

In q2, you are seeing two separate terms due to the query parser's syntax.  What is is really doing, is paring to a query like;  `names:test defaultField:three`, though it's not obvious since your default field is also "names"

In q3 (where you're note is, indeed, quite relevant!), you produce a phrase query, which isn't quite the same as the `TermQuery` you provided in q1, but with the right analyzer, it can be equivalent.  PhraseQueries are analyzed, and I'm guessing the analyzer being used by the query parser there is `StandardAnalyzer`, or something like it.  The difference is in what the terms look like:

- Terms analyzed by StandardAnalyzer:  `test` - `three`
- Terms in unanalyzed field:  `test three`

So, there are no identical terms to match between the two representations.  Instead, try using [`KeywordAnalyzer`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/KeywordAnalyzer.html), which is effectively that same as using an un-analyzed field.

You generally want to make sure you use the same analyzer in your `QueryParser` that you do to analyze your documents, with `KeywordAnalyzer` being the de-facto equivalent analyzer for an un-analyzed field.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with the following code, passing the query with quotes: `QueryParser qp = new QueryParser(GenericIndexer.LUCENE_VERSION, "names", new KeywordAnalyzer());
Query qq = qp.parse("\"test three\"");` and got the expected result. I'm a bit worried though about using a different analyzer for a specific field, would you suggest to stick with a Term Query for fields that are indexed as NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS?

Comment: Using different analyzers for different fields is fairly standard, and well supported (take a look at [PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper.html)).  Constructing a `TermQuery`, I find to be the simplest way to handle un-analyzed fields, all else being equal.  But if I need to support parsed queries across analyzed and unanalyzed fields, I'd pass a `PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper` to the QueryParser.  Whichever suits you and the situation.

Comment: @Luca - Didn't see your edit before it got rejected by the queue (it's hard to figure out the reason behind some edits like that when you just come upon it in the edit queue).  I've gone ahead and made the change now.